# Replicating CATextLayer with different string

Tags: ios, catextlayer, careplicatorlayer

I am creating gridlines using `CAReplicatorLayer`. To each gridline, I also want to add a `CATextLayer` that shows the corresponding numerical value. I do not want to do this manually, however with `CAReplicatorLayer` there doesn't seem to be a way to dynamically change the string property of each text layer, and they all show the same initial value that is set.

Is there a way around this or do I have to create and maintain the text layer objects manually?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I ended up creating an array of `CATextLayer`s and maintaining it manually alongside the gridlines created by the `CAReplicatorLayer`.